# Laurent expansion of function with singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I'm trying to get the power series expansion of the following function about $ z=0$:

$$f(z)=\frac{z^3}{1-z^4}$$

I'm having some troubles with this. Is it possible to do the following:

$$\frac{1}{1-z^4} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{4n}$$

Because if it is, then I know how to proceed.

Many thanks !

Comment: Of course, you can use that expansion.

Comment: @geetha290krm ok thanks, it seems a bit shady though that I can use it like that

Comment: Also use $z^3=\frac 1z \times z^4$ to make life easier

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici yes I used this for the next step which was to get the expansion outside the unit disk so $|z|>1$

Comment: Even shorter : do it for $-\frac 14\log(1-z^4)$ and differentiate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing shady here.   It's just the geometric series $$\dfrac 1{1-z}=\sum_{n\ge0}z^n$$, after an obvious substitution.